# Add related entry data via channel form

Tags: safecracker, relationships

I have a form that has 2 stages
each stage creates a new entry
Stage one makes an event and stage 2 makes a client

The part I'm having trouble with is making the event relate to the client

first part of the form directs the user to the next page and includes the newly created url title

```
{exp:channel:form return="make-an-event/URL_TITLE"}
```

In part 2 I want to make the client and add that created event to the clients related entry field

```
{exp:channel:form require_entry="no" channel="clients" return="thank-you"}

 <input type="text" name="cli_events:url_title[data][]" value="{segment_2}">
```

but I'm not having much luck

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was nearly there...
'{segment_2}' was url_title but it needed to be entry_id

```
{exp:channel:form return="make-an-event/ENTRY_ID"}
```

and

```
 <input type="text" name="cli_events:url_title[data][]" value="{segment_2}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed to achieve this using the following code, to relate a Job Note entry to a main Job entry:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="jobnotes" unique_url_title="yes" return="jobs/edit"}
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="Job Note" />
    <input type="hidden" name="jobnote-job[data][]" id="jobnote-job" value="entry_id_of_job" />
    {field:jobnote-main}
    <button type="submit">Add Note</button>
{/exp:channel:form}
```